# Get JSON Data - newbie here

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am using the Songkick API to list the next gig date, I have adapted the code found [here](http://www.robl.me/posts/jquery-nano-and-songkick-2). This is a copy of the [JSON data source](http://codepad.org/Kqlm1yQ9).

The HTML:

```
<head>
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.livequery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.nano.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="application.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="concerts">Loading Next Gig...</ul>
</body>
```

application.js is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var template = "<li>Our next gig is <a href='{uri}'>{displayName}</a></li>";
  var apikey = 'MY_API_KEY';
  var container = $("ul#concerts");
  $.getJSON('http://api.songkick.com/api/3.0/artists/253846/calendar.json?apikey=' + apikey + '&jsoncallback=?', function(data) {
    container.html("");
    events = data["resultsPage"]["results"]['event'];
if (events==null) {
      container.append($.nano());
}
else {
      container.append($.nano(template, events[0]));
}
  });
});
```

I would like to display for the first listed gig only,

```
event.location.city
event.venue.displayName
event.start.date (in dd MMM format).
```

If no events are listed, I would like it say something like "There are currently no gigs booked at the moment, please `[a href="example.com"] click here [/a]` for up to date information."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> - **demo:** http://jsbin.com/ocoric

```
  var events = data.resultsPage.results.event;
  $.each(events, function (i, item) {
        container.append($.nano(template, item));
    });
```

**NOTE:** since you are using `$.nano` you should iterate over the json object in order to replace the shortcode inside the template var.

if you want to access the json properties singularly you should access it like below:

```
var uri = events.uri;
var displayName = events.displayName;
```

you full code will look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var template = "<li>Our next gig is <a href='{uri}'>{displayName}</a></li>";
    var apikey = 'MY_API_KEY';
    var container = $("ul#concerts");
    $.getJSON('http://api.songkick.com/api/3.0/artists/253846/calendar.json?apikey=' + apikey + '&jsoncallback=?', function (data) {
        container.html("");
        var events = data.resultsPage.results.event;
        if (events !== null) {
      $.each(events, function (i, item) {
            container.append($.nano(template, item));
        });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Using the other responses and your example I have changed my application.js along the lines of: var template = "<li>Our next gig is <a href='{uri}'>location: {location.city} , venue: {venue.displayName}  on {start.date}</a></li>";    Thanks to everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Access the json tree with `.` (Dots)

```
events = data.resultsPage.results.event;
```

Comment: Hi Starx, thanks for coming back to me so quickly. I think I understand the method now for getting data - and I assume I can just make new variables like so: venue = data.resultsPage.results.event.location.city and the same for the other two strings I am after, but how would I then append those variables, for example container.append($.nano(template, events[0], venue[0])); ? Thanks.